# Titanium Liveview with bugs

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, liveview

Is there anyway to know if Liveview is running (like Ti.App.isLiveViewRunning)? There is some bugs with liveview that we can try to skip when using it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal flag you can check, but this will work:

```
// Runs via LiveView
if (localeStrings) {
  ..
}
```